# Approximately compare decimal attributes of a class defined with `attrs`

Tags: python-attrs

I have a `Thing` class with an float `x` attribute. And I want to approximately compare two instances of `Thing` with a relelative tolerance of 1e-5.

```
import attr

@attr.s
class Thing(object):
    x: float = attr.ib()


>>> assert Thing(3.141592) == Thing(3.1415926535)  # I want this to be true with a relelative tolerance of 1e-5
False
```

Do I need to override the `__eq__` method or is there a clean way of telling `attr` to use `math.isclose()` or a custom comparison function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setting `eq=True` and implementing your own `__eq__`/`__ne__` is your way to go.  In this case your need is so specific that I wouldn't even know how to abstract it away without making it confusing.

Comment: in a way, comparing `float`s for equality should always happen with some tolerance. It would be great to have an `attrs` configuration/setting to specify that floats should always be compared like that. Is it possible to specify  `__eq__` for one field?

Comment: Not yet,. but we are working on it: https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/pull/627